# Choosing an Audio Output Device (ASIO)

Tags: sound-card, asio

I’m trying to choose which audio output device to use with my audio player ([XMPlay](http://www.un4seen.com/xmplay.html)). It has various output plugins, including DirectSound and ASIO (don’t even get me started on the MIDI device selection!)

When I look at the output configuration list, I find the following devices.

```
ASIO - Creative ASIO
ASIO - SB Audigy 2 ASIO 24/96 [DF00]
ASIO - SB Audigy 2 ASIO [DF00]

DirectSound - SB Audigy 2 Audio [DF00]
SB Audigy 2 Audio [DF00]

…
```

By simply adding some whitespace it really becomes clear how similar the devices, and thus why I am so confused:

```
ASIO        - Creative ASIO
ASIO        - SB Audigy 2 ASIO 24/96 [DF00]
ASIO        - SB Audigy 2 ASIO       [DF00]

DirectSound - SB Audigy 2 Audio      [DF00]
              SB Audigy 2 Audio      [DF00]

…
```

Obviously using an ASIO device would be preferable (the non-ASIO devices sound much quieter), but which one? I’m fairly sure that the first and third sound the same, but the middle one (“24/96”) sounds different (not better or worse, just different, eg “wider”). Can anyone tell me what the difference between the *three* ASIO devices on the *same* card are or what the difference is between the bare card and the DirectSound entry for it?

(Also, why is it that the hexadecimal number (address?) seems to change whenever I move the card or reinstall the drivers?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally, sound cards tend to run at 16 bits and 44.1 or 48 khz or 16/48

I'd guess that that the first and third are 16 bit, and the other one is 24 bit - and you have it set to resample the output, and for some reason its making a difference. The 96 refers to the sampling rate it supports of 96 khz (the sampling rate of a cd is 44.1khz, and many devices support 48 khz)

ASIO is supposed to have lower latency than directsound (ASIO bypasses the usual sound system) and subjectively sounds better.

Comment: So what’s the difference between “Creative ASIO” and “SB Audigy 2 ASIO” or “SB Audigy 2” and “DirectSound SB Audigy 2”. I imagine that the same situation exists for other cards, with a different name (eg Audigy 4/X-Fi/etc.), so it’s not a card-dependent issue, and thus probably a generic question that should have a definitive answer.